# Content from folder on a server

Tags: python

I am working with a python script on a server with the following hierarchy:

- DreamteamPy (folder)

  - pictest.py
  - assets (folder)

    - pictures (folder)

      - 31.jpg
      - picture2.jpg
      - picture3.jpg

The complete path of the python file is

```
http://www.cytosine.nl/~owe4_pg3/Rogier/DreamteamPy/pictest.py
```

And one of the pictures:

```
http://www.cytosine.nl/~owe4_pg3/Rogier/DreamteamPy/assets/pictures/31.jpg
```

How can I get all of the files in the pictures folder?
I've tried things like

```
import os
def index():
    filelist=[]
    path= "http://www.cytosine.nl/~owe4_pg3/Rogier/DreamteamPy/assets/pictures"
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        filelist.append(filename)
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

What you call is path isn't a path but a HTTP URL.  `os.listdir()` needs a path on the local file system.  Which in your case most likely is something like `/home/owe4_pg3/html/Rogier/DreamteamPy/assets/pictures` unless it is not a typical Linux installation where a web server is configured to map `~username` at the start of the path part of an URL to `/home/username/html`.

`os.listdir()` already returns a list, so it doesn't make much sense to copy the elements one by one into another list.

```
import os

PICTURES_PATH = '/home/owe4_pg3/html/Rogier/DreamteamPy/assets/pictures'

def index():
    filenames = os.listdir(PICTURES_PATH)
```